# Second Stiefel-Whitney class and first Pontryagin class of total spaces of linear $S^2$ bundles over $S^4$

Tags: algebraic-topology, fiber-bundles

Oriented linear $S^2$ bundles over $S^4$ are classified by $\pi_3(SO(3))=\mathbb{Z}$. They all have the same cohomology groups but with different ring structure. The trivial bundle $S^2\times S^4$ has $w_2=0,\ p_1=0$; $\mathbb{CP}^3$ corresponds to the integer 1 and has $w_2=0,\ p_1=-4$.

So my question is whether the total spaces of all those bundles are spin, i.e. $w_2=0$ and what their first Pontryagin classes are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $z\in \mathbb{Z}$, let $E_z$ denote the total space of the bundle corresponding to $z$.  So, $E_0 = S^2\times S^4$ and $E_1 = \mathbb{C}P^3$.  We will show that $w_2(E_z) = 0$ and $p_1(E_z) = -4z$.

**Claim 1**: $E_z$ is the pull back of $S^2\rightarrow \mathbb{C}P^3\rightarrow S^4$ from a degree $z$ map $S^4\rightarrow S^4$.

Proof:  Consider the universal bundle $SO(3)\rightarrow ESO(3)\rightarrow BSO(3)$.  Linear $S^2$ bundles over $S^4$ are classified by a homotopy class of map from $S^4$ to $BSO(3)$.  In other words, they are classified by $\pi_4(BSO(3))$ (which is canonically isomorphic to $\pi_3(SO(3)) \cong \mathbb{Z}$ as you noted).  Also as you noted, $\mathbb{C}P^3$ corresponds to the $z=1$ case.  Let $\phi:S^4\rightarrow BSO(3)$ classify $E_1$.  In other words, $[\phi]\in\pi_4(BSO(3))\cong \mathbb{Z}$ corresponds to $1$.

Now, if $f:S^4\rightarrow S^4$ is a degree $z$ map, then clearly $[\phi\circ f] = z\in \mathbb{Z}$.  Then $E_z = (\phi \circ f)^\ast ESO(3) = f^\ast \phi^\ast ESO(3) = f^\ast \mathbb{C}P^3$. $\square$

**Claim 2**:  $w_2(E_z) = 0$.

Proof:  Let $\epsilon$ denote a trivial bundle.  Also, let $\pi:E_z\rightarrow S^4$ denote the projection.  Finally, let $\xi_z$ denote the vector bundle obtained by filling in the fibers of $E_z$.  Then $TE_z\oplus \epsilon \cong \pi^\ast TS^4 \oplus \pi^\ast \xi_z$, according to Lemma 8.2.3 of [Geiges' *"An introduction to contact topology"*](https://books.google.com/books?id=RERR4zMDYRgC&pg=PA383&lpg=PA383&dq=geiges%20oriented%20sphere%20bundle%20characteristic%20classes&source=bl&ots=NccTWspeuv&sig=kdy439cbBHEe318WDsFBaDY_Li8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjVr92_pobZAhUDc98KHT0VAcwQ6AEILzAC#v=onepage&q=geiges%20oriented%20sphere%20bundle%20characteristic%20classes&f=false).  Since both $TS^4$ and $\xi_z$ are bundles over $S^4$, the Stiefel-Whitney classes up to $w_3$ all vanish trivially.  In particular, $w_2(TE_z) = 0$ by the Whitney sum formula. $\square$

**Claim 3**:  $p_1(E_z) = -4z$.

Proof:  Using the same trick as in Claim 2, (and the fact that $p_1(TS^4) = 0$ because its stably parallelizable), we know that $p_1(TE_z) = \pi^\ast p_1(\xi_z)$.  Now a Gysin sequence argument shows that $\pi^\ast:H^4(S^4)\cong \mathbb{Z}\rightarrow  H^4(E_z)$ is an isomorphism.  So, we need only compute $p_1(\xi_z)\in H^4(S^4)$.

By definition, this is obtained by taking the pull back of $p_1\in H^4(BSO(3))$ under the classifying map $f_z\circ \phi$.  Since $p_1(\mathbb{C}P^3) = -4$, we know $\phi^\ast(p_1) = -4 \in H^4(S^4)$.  So, we have reduced the calculation to understanding $f_z^\ast :H^4(\mathbb{C}P^3)\rightarrow H^4(E_z)$.  But in [my answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76430/what-tells-rational-cohomology-about-integral-cohomology) I show that it is multiplication by $z$.  $\square$

Comment: @Chris:  Fixed.  Thanks!

Comment: The argument by Geiges seems to only work for sphere bundles which arise as sphere bundles of vector bundles. Is there any other technique for those sphere bundles which don't arise this way? (I know this isn't relevant here as every $S^2$ bundle is the sphere bundle of a rank $3$ bundle)

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese:  I don't know of any such technique.  In fact, while I know that in principle there should be non-linear sphere bundles, I don't know how to construct a single example.